# Sitecore MVC Routing and Virtual Folders

Tags: mvc, multisite, routing

I have a multi-site Sitecore instance with several sites defined using the `physicalFolder/virtualFolder` attributes defined on the `<site>` nodes all done with MVC.  There is some functionality I would like to add to a page in a more native-MVC fashion where I can invoke the controller thru Javascript and update the DOM elements on the response with the updated html from the controller (ie: `/api/sitecore/search/results`). The issue I am seeing, since I am inoking the controller directly/natively, it's a bit outside the Sitecore execution pipeline so I have no handle on the `Sitecore.Context.Site`.  Ultimately, what I would like is to do make the routing respect the virtual folder so I can at least get a handle on the `SiteContext` (ie: `/site1/api/sitecore/search/results`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I ended up doing is registering a single route on `pipelines/initialize`:

```xml
<pipelines>
    <initialize>
        <processor type="MyFramework.Routing.RegisterVirtualFoldersRoutes, MyFramework" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
    </initialize>
</pipelines>
```

and in the pipeline itself:

```cs
namespace MyFramework.Routing
{
    public class RegisterVirtualFoldersRoutes
    {
        public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("VirtualFolderRouting", "{virtualFolder}/api/sitecore/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });
        }
    }
}
```

Without any additional customization this allowed me to invoke `/site1/api/sitecore/search/results` or `/site2/api/sitecore/search/results` directly and get the `SiteContext` of the site respective of the `virtualFolder`.  I assume there *may* be some collisions between the `virtualfolder/api/sitecore` and other defined routes, but none of them come to mind currently.

Comment: This perfectly worked for my virtual paths which contain no forward slashes. thanks

Comment: In the meantime, I'm trying to find a way to make it work with site containing slashes in their virtual folder. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Alireza, could you provide an example of what kind of virtual folder you would ultimately be using?

Comment: 0

Some of my websites contain one or more "/" in their virtual folders, something like /demo/v1, /demo/v2, dev/v1, dev/v2, etc.

Due to some marketing and design restrictions, I have to put them in separate websites. I'm doing something now, and I'll share it here with you when it's done :)